# CruiseControl.NET parameter passing

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have a [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) ccnet.config file, which monitors two different projects in the same project scope. If one of them changes, it has to trigger a build. But I wanted to know which project has been changed among the two. I have to pass them as a commandline parameter. Is there any built-in property?

Comment: Why do you have both in the same project scope? Do you need to build them together?

Comment: yes. Its like I have 2 projects to monitor. 1st project is for placing the table scripts and the 2nd project contains DML statements. So whenever there is a change in the table structure, I have to drop DB and install fresh including the table+ dml+data. If 2nd project is changed, its enough to run only DML statements. When I have it as diff project there should be co-ordination between the two. If 1st proj is running, 2nd should not run and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting the project to two projects seems like the right thing to do.
Specifically, split to to projects and add a [Project trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Trigger) for the DML project.
This way if the table scripts are to be changed, both projects will be triggered and if only some DML statement changes, only the second project will be triggered.

In case both projects have common trigger then i recommend using a synchronization [queue](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Queue+Configuration).

```
<queue name="Q_Synchronizer" duplicates="UseFirst" />
<project name="project1_name" queue="Q_Synchronizer" queuePriority="1">project stuff...</project>
<project name="project2_name" queue="Q_Synchronizer" queuePriority="2">project stuff...</project>
```

HTH

Comment: But how do I control that both should not run at the same time. When 1st project is running, second should not involve and if second is running first should not involve. Synchronisation is required as they work on same DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hertzel. This works only with the cruisecontrol version 1.4.2 but I have only 1.4.0 and can't move to higher version also. Is there any other possibility with 1.4.0 version for implementing the same?

Comment: I noticed one more in running sync queue. In queue first project, it detected a change and I intentionally wait for a min for any other modifications, So it waited for that. Then the second project also detected a change and it was waiting. In this mean time, first project started building nant task. But failed. Second project even after detecting the chnage, it didnt start the nant task, rather started for checking modification again. Is this the intended ? The second proj should run after 1st project is over right?

Comment: Yeap. Its configurable using the `triggerStatus`.